# Is glue code just emulating the desired behaviour in "native" code?

Tags: binding, cross-compiling, emulation

I'm not that familiar with glue code (multiple language bindings) and I can't seem to find a very detailed description of how it is usually implemented (if there is such a way, it may be one of those problems that can be solved so many ways).

Let us take OpenGL as an example while it is written in C there are also java bindings, this is probably not the best example since java is a virtual machine and probably just maps your calls to the native interface. So how about Python (which I know almost nothing about) it has OpenGL bindings, but is not in the C family so how does it link against GL?